# Change "published by"

Tags: themes, language

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHTdu.jpg

At my blogg / news is this line is coming at a new post.
I use norwegian as language and then I want to change the word I marked yellow.

In english is "published by:"
In norwegian is would be "publisert av:", but I want it to say "Written by:" or in norwegian "Skrevet av:"

How can I fix that ?

Comment: The string should be anywhere in your theme's template file. Do a search in theme files and change it from there.

Comment: It the theme is properly [internationalized](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/) you could handle it with a translation (`.mo`) file, but that's certainly a bigger lift than swapping out a string.